# How to import a C++ class head and cpp file in a new cpp file

Tags: c++

Here is an example C++ code.

header.h

```
class example {
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    int sum(int i,int j);
};
```

cpp.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"header.h"
int example::sum(int i,int j){
    a=i;
    b=j;
    return a+b;
}
int main(){
  example e1;
  int b=e1.sum(32,34);
  std::cout<<b<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"header.h"
int main(){
  example e1;
  int b=e1.sum(32,34);
  std::cout<<b<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

When I use the code in powershell `g++ cpp.cpp`
I get a file a.exe without any problem.  When I run the main.cpp it shows the error

```
d:/program files/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KISHOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIMGM4v.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `example::sum(int, int)'
```

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

If I have to use the class in a file called main.cpp how do I it?
I am working on a bunch of files which has similar usb.cpp and usb.h file. But the cpp fle containing the main program imports only header file.
How to tell g++ that definition of the header file is given in cpp.cpp?

Comment: You need to compile and link ***both*** `main.cpp` and `cpp.cpp`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But can you explain me what the above code does. From what I know the step is preprocessing -> compiling -> linking. If I compile the above file 'g++ -c cpp.cpp main.cpp' I get two cpp.o and main.o files. How do I link these files to get an exe?

Comment: gcc has an extensive manual page that explains how it works, and what all of the options do. Did you try reading that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compile with the command `g++ cpp.cpp main.cpp`, and comment out the main function in cpp.cpp.

Comment: Thank you, that works.  But can you explain me what the above code does. From what I know the step is preprocessing -> compiling -> linking. If I compile the above file 'g++ cpp.cpp  main.cpp' I get two cpp.o and main.o  files. How do I link these files to get an exe?